# ipython notebook .png figures after nbconvert not loaded by latest chrome/firefox

Tags: html, matplotlib, ipython, python-3.3, jupyter-notebook

Running `$ipython3 notebook --pylab=inline` locally, I saved a simple notebook with a small png figure using pylab and python 3.3.

Contents of notebook cell:

```
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0, 5, 10)
y = x ** 2
figure()
plot(x, y, 'r')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
title('title')
show()
```

running the cell resulted in an inline png figure being displayed.
The saved file (my_notebook.ipynb) has a .png saved as a data uri:

`{ ..., "png":"iVBO...ZUmwK\n...", ... }`

after executing command:

`ipython3 nbconvert --to html my_notebook.html`

my_notebook.html is generated with the figure as a data uri like this:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,b'iVBO...ZUmwk\n..." >`

In latest chrome or firefox the image data uri does not load/display when opening file:///.../my_notebook.html locally and chrome console reports 'failed to load resource' for the img tag.

I have had the same results with images loaded and then displayed with imshow().
The figures appear fine in the notebook.  It is after nbconvert to html that they do not display (at all).

(notice the escaped newline in the image data uri - I tried replacing all escaped newlines in the data string with actual newlines with no change in results)

**How can I get png figures to display in an nbconverted-html-version of an ipython notebook opened locally ("file:///.../my_notebook.html") in browser?**

(I would rather not have to save each figure and hand modify the converted html to reference the saved figure on disk.)

**EDIT:**
versions:

```
python 3.3.1
ipython==1.0.0
matplotlib==1.2.1
Pillow==2.1.0 (PIL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) first:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Then use following function to freeze your generated html file. The images will be placed in the `images` folder under the same directory as the html file.

```
import os
import re
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from uuid import uuid4


def dump(path, data):
    root = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(root):
        os.makedirs(root)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    # for windows
    return path.replace('\\', '/')


def freeze_html(path):
    '''pass in absolute path of your html'''
    root = os.path.dirname(path)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        soup = BS(f.read())
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        m = re.search(r"data:image/png;base64,b'(.*)'", img['src'])
        if m:
            iname = uuid4()
            ipath = os.path.join(root, 'images', '%s.png' % iname)
            # remove '\n'
            s = m.group(1).replace(r'\n', '')
            img['src'] = os.path.relpath(
                dump(ipath, base64.b64decode(s.encode('ascii'))),
                root
            )
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

If you do not need to further convert it to tex or pdf, you can just write string (`\n` removed) back to `img['src']`(with `data:image/png;base64,` prefix):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def freeze_html(path):
    '''pass in absolute path of your html'''
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        soup = BS(f.read())
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        m = re.search(r"data:image/png;base64,b'(.*)'", img['src'])
        if m:
            # remove '\n'
            s = m.group(1).replace(r'\n', '')
            img['src'] = 'data:image/png;base64,' + s
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

I prefer to save png to separate file because it's more friendly to xelatex.

Comment: Thank you.  This does not work with the `--template full` option and it only works on the first couple images with `--template basic` option. What is your template and setup that this works for?

Comment: @user2755886 It works for me in both 'full' and 'basic', for example, [here](https://github.com/Answeror/python-course.2013/raw/master/darkmaze.ipynb). Could you post an example ipynb file?

Comment: I see that you are using `from PIL import Image`
`from IPython import display as disp`.  I am using matplotlib and pylab which use imshow to display charts/images.  Maybe this is the difference.